# Catalyst 3500 XL and Bandwidth Limiting

Tags: cisco

I have tried limiting bandwidth by port but the  srr-queue bandwidth limit command does not seem to work at all. Says command not found and i am not sure how else to do it. Is this switch even capable of limiting bandwidth by port?

Answer (score 1):

Are you in interface configuration mode, as in:

Switch(config)# interface FastEthernet 0/1

Switch(config-if)# srr-queue bandwidth limit...

Comment: yes that is not coming up with anything except command unrecognized.

Comment: What version of IOS are you running? It's possible you just need a newer, or different series, or IOS.

Comment: Yup, check your IOS version.